# Passing image object into function

Tags: javascript, jquery, particles

Im playing around with a particle emitter (all creds: [scurker.com](http://scurker.com/blog/2010/06/particle-generator-using-html5s-canvas/))

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4REVD/

Im trying to create my own image object that can be used with the framework. Im supposed to be a able to do this with:

```
particles.update(myObject);
```

What ive tried so far is:

```
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = "images/_cloud.gif";

  particles.update(myImage);
```

However that doesnt seem to do anything - besides ruining the current default flame animation

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just add another entry to effects variable?

Comment: NielsC> I havent been able to find any documentation on being able to do define the image object there. Im only noting what the author wrote in my comment just above here

Comment: Arun > Guess the author comment could just have been a reference to creating your own effects based on the options available. Does it seem theres any way to actually pass on an image to be used?